# getcontentresolver() returns null in a service

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

In the below code, the `getcontentresolver()` is null, but works in the `onCreate()` of Service but not in a function in the service. Why? plz help me..thanks

```
    final Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    final String[] cursor_cols = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA };

    final String where = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "=1";

    cursor = getContentResolver()
            .query(uri, cursor_cols, where, null, null);
```

Comment: Are you calling the function _before_ the `onCreate()` method of your `Service` has executed? E.g. calling it from the constructor or something similar?

Comment: no after start service only,just started the service in the first activty

Comment: you should add code that shows the class(es) and how you call your function in that case.

Comment: public ArrayList<MusicFile> Scan() {
  final Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
  final String[] cursor_cols = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA };

Comment: final String where = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "=1";
  cursor = getContentResolver()
    .query(uri, cursor_cols, where, null, null);

Comment: while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
   album_column_index = cursor.getInt(cursor
     .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID));

Comment: MusicFile musicFile = new MusicFile();
            final String artist = cursor.getString(cursor
     .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
            final String album = cursor.getString(cursor
     .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));

Comment: final String track = cursor.getString(cursor
     .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
   final String data = cursor.getString(cursor
     .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));

Comment: musicfilename.add(track);
   musicFile.setAlbum(album);
   musicFile.setArtist(artist);
   musicFile.setTitle(track);
   musicFile.setPath(data);
   musicFile.setClipId(album_column_index);
   files.add(musicFile);

Comment: }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
  XmlOperations.initMusicList();
  return files;
 }

Comment: am sorry but the code cant copy here compltly site shows some charters left

Comment: you can edit your question and add the code there, helps ppl reading your question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your USB connection to the device is in PC mode, and not USB Mass Storage

if it is in Mass Storage, it will return null